# Would you use "boss" about anyone who is someone else's superior?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, difference

As the heading suggests, my question today is whether you could use the word "boss" in any context where you want to refer to someone who is someone else's superior? I've found some information that suggests that "boss" is mostly used in non-academic contexts, but I'm not sure I've got this right.

More specifically, could I use "boss" in an academic context, for instance referring to the head of department as the various teachers' boss, or to the dean as the boss of faculty staff? If not, what word should I use instead, in contexts where I need to refer to someone's superior, but where I can't give their exact title (such as head of dept or dean)?

Grateful as always for your help!

Comment: _Boss_ is generally not a good word to use in anything other than a fairly informal context; it's better to use words like _supervisor_ or _manager_ where an exact title (such as _Dean_, _Director_, etc.) is not known.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Thank you! So can you use "supervisor" even in a context where the person in question doesn't strictly speaking supervise anyone?

Comment: In a case like that, you'd need to know more about the relationship, and describe it. As an example, the Deputy Commissioner (actual title) of the division of my organization that I work in is several levels above me, so he's really neither my manager nor my supervisor; he's "the Deputy Commissioner", or, if someone doesn't know our titles, "the  department head".

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Oh, ok... Well – thank you very much for your help anyway!

Comment: If you know approximately where in a hierarchy a person is, you can always use a phrase like "line supervisor" or "low/mid/high-level manager".

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Well, the context I need it for is a context where I need to refer to a number of different "bosses" (for lack of a better word) at different levels and different functions – the head of a department; the head of the faculty office; and so on. But perhaps I could phrase it like this "As newly employed staff, you will be introduced to the workplace by your closest superior"?

Comment: ...by your *immediate* superior.